# Implementing Inheritable Style objects in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance

In our data layer, we need to create "style" objects that could inherit their values from other "style" objects.

**Example scenario 1:**

```
class Style
{
   string Name;
   string ParentName;
   // Other properties go here.
}
```

So, when there is a list of such styles, a style with a parent name should *inherit it's style values from it's parent*.

**Scenario 2:**

```
class ConatiningType
{
    Style BaseStyle;
    Style MouseHoverStyle;
}
```

In the above case, the *MouseHoverStyle should inherit it's values from the BaseStyle*.

I am sure there are some recommended design patterns for this scenario. If so, please point to those.

Comment: Are you familiar with Dependency Properties?

Comment: Are you trying to duplicate the Style inheritance in WPF? I assume this is for WinForms?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `Style` itself should have a `ParentStyle`:

```
class Style
{
   private readonly Style parentStyle;

   private string name;

   public string Name
   {
       get { return name ?? (parentStyle == null ? null : parentStyle.Name); }
       set { name = value; }
   }

   public Style(Style parentStyle)
   {
       this.parentStyle = parentStyle;
   }
}
```

Having to use the null check on `parentStyle` is somewhat annoying, admittedly :( You could construct a "default" version like this, of course:

```
class Style
{
   private static readonly Style DefaultStyle = new Style(null) {
       Name = "",
       ... 
   };

   private readonly Style parentStyle;

   private string name;

   public string Name
   {
       get { return name ?? parentStyle.Name); }
       set { name = value; }
   }

   public Style(Style parentStyle)
   {
       this.parentStyle = parentStyle ?? DefaultStyle;
   }
}
```

Note that the `DefaultStyle` would *still* have a null `parentStyle` (as `DefaultStyle` would be null during its construction) but if you gave it actual default values ("", 0 etc) then it would never try to defer to its own non-existent parent.

Comment: Thanks, it's a perfectly valid answer.

But, I am looking for a much more elaborate "pattern" that is a lot more scalable and performant, takes into account a lot more scenarios of "value inheritance" (is that the word I am looking for?), besides the 2 scenarios I outlined above.

Thanks

Comment: @rqtechie: Where do you see the performance problems? It's hard to suggest approaches which will work for scenarios you haven't described...